# Transform list<byte[], int> to list<byte[]>

Tags: f#

I have an `list<tuple<byte[], int>>`. How can I discard the `int` and end up with a `list` of `byte[]`?

The intellisense info looks like this.

```
 Task.Result : (byte[] * int) list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input |> List.map fst` will do the trick:

```
> let input = [ ([| 1uy |], 1); ([| 20uy |], 20) ];;
val input : (byte [] * int) list = [([|1uy|], 1); ([|20uy|], 20)]

> input |> List.map fst;;
val it : byte [] list = [[|1uy|]; [|20uy|]]
```

It will map each element in the input collection using [`fst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.fst['t1,'t2]-function-[fsharp]) function, which takes the first element of a tuple and discards all the other elements.